# Detecting interesting parts of video with ML Kit

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

Is there a way to detect interesting things in the video with the ML Kit or any other SDK on mobile?
I would like to pick the video and get the start and stop durations for interesting parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the [Fast-Video-Frame-Extraction](https://github.com/duckyngo/Fast-Video-Frame-Extraction) to extract all the frames in video with high speed then apply MLKit on all frames.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how to define "interesting". Here is a list of thoughts:

You could use image labeling to find the interested labels in the images or face detection to indicate when a face appears in the frames or disappear from the frames. Or you could use pose detection to see a strange pose appears or more.